# Django unit testing for form edit

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-forms

Someone has probably already developed a technique for relieving the tedium for the following idiomatic unit test:

1. GET a url with form data already populated
2. POST a revised form with one or more fields edited
3. Check response (profit!)

Step 2 is the most tedious, cycling through the form fields.  Are there any time-saving hacks for testing Django forms?

[*Update*: I'm not testing Django forms handling.  I'm verifying that my application produces correct responses when a user makes changes to a form.  This is an application which processes clinical information, hence a lot of possible responses to test.]

Comment: Are you writing tests that have those three steps for each field of the form?  And your forms have a lot of fields?  You have a lot of fields to test?  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Lot of forms, lots of fields.  But each test is a test for a particular outcome (e.g. does the app properly inform the the user who fails to fully qualify a diagnosis), not a test of each field.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to test. I would target your tests a bit more finely than it sounds like you are doing.

If the code you need to test is the form validation logic, then I would simply instantiate the form class directly in your tests, pass it various data dictionaries and call .is_valid(), check for the proper errors or lack thereof. No need to involve HTML or HTTP requests.

If it's view logic (which IMO should be minimized) that you are testing, you will probably want to use the test client, but you shouldn't need to do multi-stage tests or very many tests at this level. In testing view logic I wouldn't scrape HTML (that's testing templates), I'd use response.context to pull out the form object from the context.

If what you want to test is that the templates contain the proper HTML to make the form actually work (in order to catch errors like forgetting to include the management form for a formset in the template), I use [WebTest](http://pythonpaste.org/webtest/) and [django-webtest](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-webtest), which parse your HTML and make it easy to fill in field values and submit the form like a browser would.

Comment: "I'd use response.context to pull out the form object"  <-- Doing this now. Not really testing HTML, just the outcomes of a process.  Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `response.context` and `form.initial` to get the values you need to post:

```
update_url = reverse('myobject_update',args=(myobject.pk,))

# GET the form
r = self.client.get(update_url)

# retrieve form data as dict
form = r.context['form']
data = form.initial # form is unbound but contains data

# manipulate some data
data['field_to_be_changed'] = 'updated_value'

# POST to the form
r = self.client.post(update_url, data)

# retrieve again
r = self.client.get(update_url)
self.assertContains(r, 'updated_value') # or
self.assertEqual(r.context['form'].initial['field_to_be_changed'], 'updated_value')
```

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant, but I'm working on a project stuck on Django 1.02 and it's r.context[0]["form"] to get at the form.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly for functionally testing views that use Forms / ModelForms!

Comment: Note, the name "form" is not guaranteed, and depends on the context name used in your view. e.g. If you doing this to test Django's admin, the name is "adminform".

Comment: Also note that this doesn't work at all for admin's auto-generated inline forms.

Comment: too bad that form.initial contains Python objects rather than strings which makes the test deviate from what would actually happen when passing through the render-browser loop

Answer (score 23):

[django-webtest](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-webtest) is perfect for such tests:

```
from django_webtest import WebTest

class MyTestCase(WebTest):
    def test_my_view(self)
        form = self.app.get('/my-url/').form
        self.assertEqual(form['my_field_10'].value, 'initial value')
        form['field_25'] = 'foo'
        response = form.submit() # all form fields are submitted
```

In my opinion it is better than twill for django testing because it provides access to django internals so native django's `response.context`, `response.templates`, `self.assertTemplateUsed` and `self.assertFormError` API is supported.

On other hand it is better than native django test client because it has much more powerful and easy API.

I'm a bit biased ;) but I believe that django-webtest is now the best way to write django tests.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear but one guess is that you have tests like this.

```
class TestSomething( TestCase ):
    fixtures = [ "..." ]
    def test_field1_should_work( self ):
        response= self.client.get( "url with form data already populated" )
        form_data = func_to_get_field( response )
        form_data['field1']= new value
        response= self.client.post( "url", form_data )
        self.assert()
    def test_field2_should_work( self ):
        response= self.client.get( "url with form data already populated" )
        form_data = func_to_get_field( response )
        form_data['fields']= new value
        response= self.client.post( "url", form_data )
        self.assert()
```

First, you're doing too much.  Simplify.

```
class TestFormDefaults( TestCase ):
    fixtures = [ "some", "known", "database" ]
    def test_get_should_provide_defaults( self ):
        response= self.client.get( "url with form data already populated" )
        self.assert(...)
```

The above proves that the defaults populate the forms.

```
class TestPost( TestCase ):
    fixtures = [ "some", "known", "database" ]
    def test_field1_should_work( self ):
        # No need to GET URL, TestFormDefaults proved that it workd.
        form_data= { expected form content based on fixture and previous test }
        form_data['field1']= new value
        response= self.client.post( "url", form_data )
        self.assert()
```

Don't waste time doing a "get" for each "post".  You can prove -- separately -- that the GET operations work.  Once you have that proof, simply do the POSTs.

If you POSTS are highly session-specific and stateful, you can still do a GET, but don't bother parsing the response.  You can prove (separately) that it has exactly the right fields.

To optimize your resting, consider this.

```
class TestPost( TestCase ):
    fixtures = [ "some", "known", "database" ]
    def test_many_changes_should_work( self ):
        changes = [
            ( 'field1', 'someValue', 'some expected response' ),
            ( 'field2', 'someValue' ),
            ...
        ]
        for field, value, expected in changes:
            self.client.get( "url" ) # doesn't matter what it responds, we've already proven that it works.
            form_data= { expected form content based on fixture and previous test }
            form_data[field]= value
            response self.client.post( "url", form_data )
            self.assertEquas( expected, who knows what )
```

The above will obviously work, but it makes the number of tests appear small.

Comment: Upvoted because it's the most useful response so far.  I'm basically doing your optimization now.  GET is already in a separate test, but I'm using it here to replace line: "form_data={ expected form content based on fixture and previous test }", as I'm iterating through auto-generated fixtures and it saves the work of manually typing out the details.

Comment: @Jeff Bauer: "it saves the work of manually typing out the details"?  What?  So does refactoring the default data into `setUp` or a superclass or a separate function.  There are a million programming techniques to reduce redundancy, all of which can be used in unit testing.  Why aren't you simply refactoring the tedious parts?  I don't understand what's so hard about designing a test class that's somehow optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Think carefully about why you need to unit-test this. Forms are part of the core Django functionality, and as such are very well covered by Django's own unit tests. If all you're doing is basic create/update, which from your question it sounds like is the case, I don't see any reason to write unit tests for that.

Comment: Maybe he has custom validation.

Comment: Yes, lots of custom validation.  Believe me, I'm not looking to create more work for myself. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly looking for tools that do front end testing like [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) or [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Both of these generate python code, that can be included within the django tests, so when you run tests, it opens the urls, posts the data and inspects whatever you want!

It should help you to see [these tests](http://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth/blob/master/socialauth/tests.py) written for selenium, for an open source reusable django app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how or why you need unit tests for this. Sounds to me like you're testing for (and correcting) possible user input, which is covered very simply with Django's form validation (and model validation in 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommed you to take a look into acceptance testing level tools like robot test framework or letucce which are thought just for you want to do "I'm verifying that my application produces correct responses when a user makes changes to a form", that sounds more like acceptance (black-box) testing than unit-testing.

For instace, Robot let you to define your tests in tabular form, you define the workflow once and then you can define easily a bunch of tests that exercise the workflow with different data.